# how to reduce png image filesize in PIL

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I have used PIL to convert and resize JPG/BMP file to PNG format. I can easily resize and convert it to PNG, but the file size of the new image is too big.

```py
im = Image.open('input.jpg')
im_resize = im.resize((400, 400), Image.ANTIALIAS)  # best down-sizing filter
im.save(`output.png')
```

What do I have to do to reduce the image file size?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optimize .png images with PIL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991929/optimize-png-images-with-pil)

Comment: Also: [How to reduce the image file size using PIL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10607468)

Comment: Last but not least, set the `optimize` option when saving: `im.save(filename, optimize=True)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PNG Images still have to hold all data for every single pixel on the image, so there is a limit on how far you can compress them.

One way to further decrease it, since your 400x400 is to be used as a "thumbnail" of sorts, is to use indexed mode:

im_indexed = im_resize.convert("P")
im_resize.save(...  )

****wait **** 
Just saw an error in your example code:
You are saving the original image, not the resized image:

```
im=Image.open(p1.photo)
im_resize = im.resize((400, 400), Image.ANTIALIAS)    # best down-sizing filter
im.save(str(merchant.id)+'_logo.'+'png')
```

When you should be doing:

```
im_resize.save(str(merchant.id)+'_logo.'+'png')
```

You are just saving back the original image, that is why it looks so big. Probably you won't need to use indexed mode them.

Aother thing: Indexed mode images can look pretty poor - a better way out, if you come to need it, might be to have your smalle sizes saved as .jpg instead of .png s - these can get smaller as you need, trading size for quality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other tools like [PNGOUT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNGOUT)